# Run multiple IQueryable's at single point of execution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I have a method, that when passed a parameter returns an IQueryable. In all this method is used to generate 13 separate IQueryable's.

The end result I require is to get 13 different counts of my record set within the IQueryables, however to make this more efficient than my current implementation which is:

```
var foo = iQueryableObject.Count();
var bar = iSecondQueryableObject.Count();
```

I'd like to run all the counts on the SQL server at a single point of execution, so in theory something like this:

```
var foobar = new IQueryable<object>[]
{
    iQueryableObject.DeferredExecutionCount(),
    iSecondQueryableObject.DeferredExecutionCount()
}.ToList();
```

Does anyone have any ideas to how I can achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at [future queries](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Future-Queries).

Comment: That looks interesting, I'll check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try this against the actual database, but you can use `GroupBy`, and `Union` (or `Concat`) to achieve this.

Consider the following POCOs (your EF entities):

```
class Thing
{
    public string One { get; set;}
}

class Thang
{
    public string Two { get; set;}
}
```

Now your queries:

```
var foo= Things
    .Where(t => t.One == "One") //or whatever your filtering condition
    .GroupBy(t => t.One)
    .Select(t => new {Key = "FirstQuery", Count = t.Count()});

var bar = Thangs
    .Where(t => t.Two == "Two")
    .GroupBy(t => t.Two)
    .Select(t => new {Key = "SecondQuery", Count = t.Count()});

var deferredCounts = foo.Concat(bar).ToList();
```

Comment: That's great. I've managed to test this now and I've confirmed it does defer the execution of the count as requested. Cheers.